# Loading high res background image

Tags: css, background, loading

I have a colourful background image that is 2000px x 1500px and because of the details I am saving it as a jpeg that renders at 1.1 MB. I am using the CSS background property to render the image. So being relatively new to web dev and working with a client/designer that's not open to a change of design at this point in the process, what should I do to help this image load blazingly fast. I don't know if it makes a difference but the site is using Joomla 1.5.9. This is something I've always wanted to understand but have had trouble uncovering solutions for... I hope someone can help!!

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Nothing will make the image download any quicker on its own. I would say a 1.1MB background image is unacceptable.

Comment: you may think it is unacceptable, but the site about.me a fairly popular social network uses images about this size.

Comment: I don't see any 1.1MB images on about.me, maybe you can provide an example? That's really on the far side of acceptable considering you haven't loaded anything but the background and you are already over a MB. That page is going to be unbelievably slow on anything that isn't fast broadband. Giving the image a couple second head start does not change the fact that the page will be slow to load.

Comment: Oh yeah - update the Joomla install before you do anything else. You are 12 versions old and you have a high likelihood of being hacked. You are missing a ton of important security fixes.

Comment: Here is the url that I went to that made me think it's possible to use a larger image. Does anyone know how they are rendering this? : http://livetour.mas.be/uk/ Also, thanks for letting me know to update Joomla.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no way to make images magically load faster. Sometimes, though, splitting an image in smaller images allows for surprising size gains; so if it's not out of question for your CSS layout (it typically is, though), you could try this.

Another possibility for you would be to use [progressive JPEG](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/jpeg-faq/part1/section-11.html) images. They are encoded in such a way that enables browsers to display a progressively more precise image as it loads. This means that at first, the image appears blurry (or incomplete) but with full-dimensions, then it progressively gets sharper and better. It's well-suited for images meant to load slowly (or at least, images acknowledged to load slowly).

Comment: I found a tool called Image Optim for Mac OSX machines (http://imageoptim.pornel.net/)... pretty effective for decreasing image file sizes... any thoughts on this app?

Comment: @art_wired Well, looking at the screenshot, it seems to save 6-7% per image. I suppose it can't hurt, but I don't think it's a "universal" solution to all your image size problems.

Answer (score 3):

The best thing that you can do is try to shrink the file size to as small as possible. Let this be using some type of optimizer, smush.it for example. If you created the background image try saving it as progressive first, it loads a lower res version first then finishes loading. But the best thing is to try to shrink the size of the image width and height by finding a repeating pattern and cropping just that portion out and using it. Most about.me images are no larger than 100kb in size that are above 1200px wide.

Answer (score 1):

you could immediatley call the image in the head by using

```
<script>
(new Image()).src = "IMAGE PATH";
</script>
```

and make sure you compress the image as much as you can with different programs, or if you have photoshop cs5 you can save it for a web device to strip out all of the extra junk, you can try yahoo's smush.it

http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/

or you could delay the loading of the site entirely for a few seconds, until you can be sure that the image is loading, you could try something like hiding all of the elements and fading them in upon a setTimeout something like

*CSS

```
body{
opacity:0;
}
```

*jQuery

```
setTimeout(function(){$('body').animate({opacity:'1'},300)},5000);
```

although that may not be all that practical.

Comment: The script will execute with about the same precedence as the CSS, so it won't preload anything at all.

Comment: by using the opacity you can be sure that the images will still load, rather than using something like display:none;

Comment: yeah this is true, but stick it before calling the css file, to give it a jump start.

Comment: I don't think you're jumpstarting anything by loading it through Javascript. At best, you're delaying its layout a little.

Answer (score 0):

Would loading the background image after the rest of the page has loaded work for you? At least this way visitors will be able to use the rest of your site until the 1.1MB has loaded.

Something along the lines of setting the `style` attribute of the `<body>` to be `background: url(image.jpg)` within an onload function?

Comment: Background is already loaded asynchronously to the contents of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Delivering the image over a CDN will likely speed things up; the better ones are usually optimized to deliver the proper TCP packet size/MTU to the wide variety of clients out there and have generally done a lot of work in the details of delivering things quickly. Slow connections like cellphones will still hate you for it, but getting things like packet size right can make the most of the bandwidth that is available.